# Set Client-Side Accessible Cookie In Express

Tags: node.js, cookies, express, socket.io

I'm working on a Node app that uses Express and SocketIO. I want to set a cookie in my Express controller which is then accessible from my client-side Javascript code. Everything that I try doesn't seem to work:

```
res.setHeader('Set-Cookie','test=value');
res.cookie('rememberme', 'yes', { maxAge: 900000 });
```

Is there something I'm missing here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Might help to show the client-side code.

Comment: I'm just going into the Chrome inspector and looking at the cookies. Not seeing anything though...

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Figured it out! By default Express sets the option httpOnly to true. This means that your cookies cannot be accessed by the client-side Javascript. In order to correctly set cookies accessible on the client just use a snippet like the following:

```
res.cookie('rememberme', 'yes', { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: false});
```

I've also noticed that if you call this command and then call res.redirect, the cookie won't get set. This command needs to be followed by res.render at some point in order for it to work. Not sure why this is.

Comment: That's a good information. By any chance do you know how to access a client side cookie in server side in express framework ?

Comment: @user644745 you can read cookies in Express by looking at the `res.cookies` object.  For example, a cookie named `session_id` would exist at `res.cookies.session_id`.  http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.cookies

Comment: The reason why you need to call res.render or res.send is because setting the cookie does not initiate the response. Send and Render do. This cookie method just adds a cookie to the response object.

Comment: Just note that it is dangerous to set the _httpOnly_ flag to false for the session cookie.  When set to false, a malicious actor who has compromised a website - for example, through a simple XSS script injection attack - would be able to read and copy that session and use it to log in as the target user from another computer.  Make sure you only use that flag with cookies that don't hold any sensitive data.

Comment: @frontendbeauty Surely you mean `req.cookies` not `res.cookies`.

Comment: @dshipper, and we get this cookie value in another js files ?

Comment: Can you help with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73253135/unable-to-set-cookie-from-express-js-session-in-brave-firefox-etc-browsers-and

Answer (score 5):

Actually I have experienced the same issue for couple of hours.

Here is my code:

```
res.cookie("mycookie", "1234567890", { secure:true, maxAge:120000, httpOnly: true });
```

I can see the Set-Cookie instruction in response header, but in Chrome I can not find the cookie and I can not find the cookie by req.cookies['mycookie'].

The root cause of this problem is that I did not use HTTPS connection. (Express 4.x with cookie-parser middleware)

According to this document: [Simple Steps to Secure Your Express Node App](http://scottksmith.com/blog/2014/09/04/simple-steps-to-secure-your-express-node-application/)

If I set the option secure=true, then the browser will not send my cookie in any HTTP request but HTTPS secure connection. Then after I removed secure:true option, I got my cookie work.

Answer (score 0):

so to access in http can we use:

```
res.cookie("mycookie", "1234567890", { secure:false, maxAge:120000, httpOnly: true });?
```