# Hide cookies from document.cookie

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I opened cookie browser for firefox, I noticed that my localhost(php/apache) has a cookie named sessid. But when I tried

`document.cookie`

in the browser, the result is "", how is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cookies created by some server side application (or PHP) can be marked as `httpOnly`. Then these cookies are not visible to javascript on client side, however, the cookies are still transmitted in http(s) requests.

PHP Session cookies are marked as `httpOnly`, thus, you cannot access them using `document.cookie`.

The reason for this feature was to mitigate some cross-site scripting attacks (cookie stealing).

Comment: so is it possible to implement this ```httpOnly``` in node.js? I know how to set cookies in response header but not httpOnly

Comment: This was already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966689/set-client-side-accessible-cookie-in-express