# Why cannot retrieve cookie from XHR even it is displayed on browser console

Tags: javascript, ajax, cookies, xmlhttprequest

I make an AJAX call using the built-in API :  `XMLHttpRequest` class .

```
  var xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest()

  xhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:7878/api/map", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
  xhttp,send(`{layer:1}`);
```

The request is done successfully , I inspect the browser console & I got the info about the response of  that ajax request,  including `cookies` :

[image]

Even cookies are displayed on the browser inspector , The following instruction returns `null` .

```
xhttp.getResponseHeader('Set-Cookie')
```

How to parse response' cookies using Javascript ?

## Update : FYI :

The server of this response (i mean `localhost:7878`) has the following response configuration :

```
    response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
    response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Set-Cookie, Content-Type, Accept');
    response.header('Content-Type', 'json/application; charset=utf-8');
    response.header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Set-Cookie");
```

Comment: Afaik you can *never* access the `Set-Cookie` header, e.g. for security in the case it contains `http-only`. Just use `document.cookie`.

Comment: You might mean [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10974675/747579) . If so, `httpOnly:false` is not enough , need to be followed by `res.render` ...